# laravel 5.5 global scope is deleted

Tags: php, laravel, scope, eloquent

I have a problem that I want to solve but I can not figure out. First of all I would like to mention that I use Laravel 5.5 version. Here is the issue ;

```
<?php
class Product extends Model{

   use WithPassive, WithPrivate;

   public static function boot(){
       parent::boot();

       parent::observe( ProductObserver::class );
   }

}
```

My model file is above. As shown in the model file, there are 2 GlobalScope traits. These are added as defaults.

```
sql
   SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `products`.'is_public' = 1 AND `products`.'is_private' = 0
```

What I want to do is remove these global scopes according to a certain criterion.

```
<?php
public static function boot(){
       parent::boot();

       static::addGlobalScope('xxx', function(Builder $builder){
           if(...){
               $builder->withoutGlobalScopes([
                   ActiveScope::class,
                   PublicScope::class,
               ]);
           }
       });

       parent::observe( ProductObserver::class );
   }
```

When I dump the builder, the related global scope is deleted, though it is not actually deleted.

```
<?php
   dump(Products::toSql());
```

Unfortunately, when I run the command, the global scope is still in place.
I would ask your assistance in this matter.

Comment: could you test this way :  public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

       if(1>2)
       {
           static::addGlobalScope(new YourScope);
       }
    }

Comment: Can you show the code for `WithPassive` and `WithPrivate`?

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi not worked.

Comment: `trait WithPassive { /** * @return void */ public static function bootWithPassive() { static::addGlobalScope( new ActiveScope() ); } } `

`trait WithPrivate { /** * @return void */ public static function bootWithPrivate() { static::addGlobalScope( new PublicScope() ); } }`